# Finding and replacing dynamic values / placeholders in php

Tags: php

So I'm working on a system that will replace placeholders in a string.

String example:

```
$string = 'Meatloaf beef landjaeger porchetta swine t-bone boudin salami doner turkey capicola. [IMG1] Pork loin doner capicola chicken filet mignon. Swine sausage sirloin short ribs bresaola bacon picanha kielbasa fatback. Andouille turducken pastrami, beef ribs bacon chicken biltong t-bone pancetta spare ribs shankle pork belly ground round brisket. Pastrami pork t-bone bresaola shoulder. Landjaeger short ribs tenderloin kielbasa, [IMG3] shank picanha spare ribs pig chuck. Sausage pastrami [billede1] kielbasa pig meatloaf t-bone shankle jowl tongue ham hock tail cow.';
```

Each string will contain [IMG1] where the number will reference an id which I will need to looking in my database.

So the goal is to find each id and replace each "tag" with an image url instead.

- How can I iterate through the string to get al tags and then place them with a new value?
- Each string will have different placeholders with [IMG+randomNumber], so I need to find each ID, so I can use it to lookup my DB for the image name etc.

Comment: what are the replacement values for `[IMG1]` and others?

Comment: The replace values would simply be something like "hotdog.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a "*replacement list*"(lookup table) beforehand, otherwise DB query should be sent for each found placeholder.
The solution using `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$lookup_list = [
    'IMG1' => 'image1.jpg',
    'IMG2' => 'image2.jpg',
    'IMG3' => 'image3.jpg',
];

$string = 'Meatloaf beef landjaeger porchetta swine t-bone boudin salami doner turkey capicola. [IMG1] Pork loin doner capicola chicken filet mignon. Swine sausage sirloin short ribs bresaola bacon picanha kielbasa fatback. Andouille turducken pastrami, beef ribs bacon chicken biltong t-bone pancetta spare ribs shankle pork belly ground round brisket. Pastrami pork t-bone bresaola shoulder. Landjaeger short ribs tenderloin kielbasa, [IMG3] shank picanha spare ribs pig chuck. Sausage pastrami [billede1] kielbasa pig meatloaf t-bone shankle jowl tongue ham hock tail cow.';

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("/\[(\w+)\]/", function($m) use($lookup_list) {
    return (isset($lookup_list[$m[1]]))? $lookup_list[$m[1]] : $m[0];
}, $string);


print_r($replaced);
```

The output:

```
Meatloaf beef landjaeger porchetta swine t-bone boudin salami doner turkey capicola. image1.jpg Pork loin doner capicola chicken filet mignon. Swine sausage sirloin short ribs bresaola bacon picanha kielbasa fatback. Andouille turducken pastrami, beef ribs bacon chicken biltong t-bone pancetta spare ribs shankle pork belly ground round brisket. Pastrami pork t-bone bresaola shoulder. Landjaeger short ribs tenderloin kielbasa, image3.jpg shank picanha spare ribs pig chuck. Sausage pastrami [billede1] kielbasa pig meatloaf t-bone shankle jowl tongue ham hock tail cow.
```

Comment: So it would be best to get all img info from my DB before I replace in the string, instead of finding the id's in the text and then get data from DB?

Comment: Normally it will be 3-8, depending on the text, but that's the case for most of them

Answer (score 0):

Assign url values to the variables and insert the variables in the string instead of the tags.

```
$IMG1 = "<some url>";
$string = "Meatloaf beef landjaeger porchetta swine t-bone boudin salami doner turkey capicola. [$IMG1]";
```

Comment: I will not know the placeholder names beforehand, that's why I need to "scan" the string for placeholder values. In some strings it can be [IMG213] and will be different in all other strings. So it's not always just [IMG1], [IMG2] etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preg_replace_callback()` function:

```
<?php
$string = 'Meatloaf beef landjaeger porchetta swine t-bone boudin salami doner turkey capicola. [IMG1] Pork loin doner capicola chicken filet mignon. Swine sausage sirloin short ribs bresaola bacon picanha kielbasa fatback. Andouille turducken pastrami, beef ribs bacon chicken biltong t-bone pancetta spare ribs shankle pork belly ground round brisket. Pastrami pork t-bone bresaola shoulder. Landjaeger short ribs tenderloin kielbasa, [IMG3] shank picanha spare ribs pig chuck. Sausage pastrami [billede1] kielbasa pig meatloaf t-bone shankle jowl tongue ham hock tail cow.';


$string = preg_replace_callback(
'/\[.*?\]/',
function ($matches) {
    if(stristr($matches[0], '[IMG') !== FALSE) {
        $tag = substr($matches[0],1,-1);
        $id = (int)str_replace('IMG','',$tag);
        return "<img src='imageurl-".$id."'>";
    }elseif($matches[0] == '[billede1]'){
        return "billede1-REPLACED";
    }

},
    $string
);

echo $string;
```